# How to name the namespace of my new project?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm going to create a new library that renders genome annotations into charts. However, as C++ doesn't have a centralized library website like Perl, how do I know if the namespace conflicts with any existing one?

Comment: Why not name it `XnoDraw::`, then?

Comment: `xd` make it sound like an internet meme `lol::`, `rly::` and `yolo::`, `XnoDraw::` is better in my opinion, the only thing to notice is that often times names are patented or protected by the law, so be sure to pick a name that is "free".

Comment: To close voters: this is neither subjective nor off-topic. Finding a unique name for a library is part of library design, and there are language usage issues here too.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: it's pure marketing, it has absolutely nothing with the design.

Comment: @SergeyK. Is a name collision merely a marketing issue? Is it worthwhile to review namespace aliases here? The answers reveal the significance of the question, although it's sad that people are so close-happy that they must.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Name collision of what? Of library names? No, it's all about marketing and fancy names: libcorkscrew, libskia, libiberty, libunity, and many others.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: `Do you think "X" is a good namespace` is opinion based. How to avoid namespace collisions isn't.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Then the best option to avoid namespaces collision is to generate a 128-bit GUID for it. Why nobody does it?

Comment: @SergeyK. Actually some do use UUIDs (or random alphanumeric strings, whatever). You just wouldn't notice because it would be hidden by a namespace alias in actual use. Some people do the same for header guards. Try Googling about these things before making a presumption. And you just rattled off a list of files from your `/lib` directory, not C++ namespaces.

Comment: @Hasturkun And do you think OP is looking for a yes/no answer about `xd` in particular, or some kind of analysis about what makes a name better? It's mystifying how narrow-minded programmers tend to be.

Comment: @Potatoswatter The question was "how do I know if the namespace conflicts with any existing one", to which the only reasonable answer is to either make your namespace unique (as suggested by Pete Becker), or to check if it is so. leaving the second half, which asked for opinions. (I did vote to reopen, though)

Comment: I think naming is a serious issue for program design, especially for me who has many unsuccessful experiences on that. Previously I created some small projects with bad names, and I noticed there are many bad library names on CPAN. That is why I ask this question here.

Comment: @SergeyK.: It's unacceptable for the accuse of marketing. Firstly, how can you ask a question without showing any real example? That would be a bad question, because it's vague. In the second, if referring to the name of a real product constitutes marketing, people refer to _java_, _android_ and _c#_ so frequently (top tags), so they are all marketing for Oracle, Google and Microsoft? It's ridiculous. At last, my project is not going to use that name at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, `xd` is not a good name: it's too short. It could be a good alias in a limited context, but for a library that will be used by others, provide a long, descriptive name. Then users can select an alias that makes sense for their project.

```
namespace my_company {
namespace XnoDraw {
// ...
} // namespace XnoDraw
} // namespace my_company

// user code, not your code:
namespace xd = my_company::XnoDraw;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use anything except `std`.
Note that c++ doesn't allow compound names for namespaces.

For instance:

```
// Allowed
namespace a
{
    namespace b
    {
        int c;
    }
}

// Not allowed
namespace a::b
{
    int c;
}
```

Comment: You have to write `namespace` twice to open two namespaces, but the set of available names is the same either way.